# Why does the image leave the margins of its parent container when I increase the width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, positioning

I have spent some time trying to work this out but with no luck.
I’m trying to align the text elements along side the image like this picture below. I was able to do this with absolute positioning.

[absolute positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIKC3.jpg)

However I also want my page to be responsive so I decided to use a flex box container to put the text elements and the image elements side by side and get the equal distancing when I resized the window. However when I increase the size of my image the content area just ignore its padding margins and parent container. It creates a scroll on the window width and a plain white background.

[responsive image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx9Ze.png)

Would love to hear what people think I’m doing wrong. Would also like to hear any other ways that people would go about creating the desired effect I’m looking for.

This is my code below

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="justify">
                 <div class="inline">
                 <h1>App name</h1>
                 <h2>Download on the app store!</h2>
                 <a href="https://www.apple.com/uk/app-store/" target="_blank"><img class="downloadimg" src="appstore.png" alt="download link">
                </a>
                </div>
                <div class="inline">
                <img class="werewolf" src="werewolf.png" alt="app logo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>

CSS code:

body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', cursive;
}
header{
    background-color: aqua;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-bottom:10%;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);

}
.justify{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
   
}
.downloadimg{
    width: 50%;
}
.inline{
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    
}
.werewolf{  
    width: 140%;
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your image css rules:

```css
    image.werewolf {
        display: block; /* or inline-block */
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto; /* to maintain aspect ratio */
    }
```